# Why there are no sent mails after the Jenkins ext. mail step?

Tags: java, email, jenkins, smtp

I have configured SMTP and the postpone extended email step. Jenkins is white listed, so I do not need to specify the credentials. 
Job finishes successful. But why it does not sends anything?

Second problem. I had some "successful" ext. email step runs with "no emails were triggered" result.

Full images: 
http://s16.postimg.org/5074itjub/image.jpg

http://s17.postimg.org/5dghc1br1/image.jpg

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check what **triggers** a sending email.

I'm not sure if your second printscreen contains all configuration. But there I can see that only "Any failure" triggers sending email. So if job finished successfully no email were sent.

======== EDITED ========

See at following printscreen how triggers may look like:
[image]